# how to use privoxy with http proxy as parent that requires authentication?

Tags: windows, proxy, squid, privoxy

How can i forward http parent proxy using privoxy when parent proxy requires authentication.
I had read something about headers but i have no idea how to add headers in privoxy config .

Answer (score 1):

Browser will show authentication dialog if you use proxy requires authentication.

And you can add this to privoxy config file (you will don't need to enter password more times)

enable-proxy-authentication-forwarding 1

Comment: Is it not possible to set the username and password of the parent proxy in the privoxy config file? This would be needed for some apps, since they will not display an authentication dialog like a web browser.